# How do I access data in array using javascript TEMPO

Tags: javascript, arrays, tempo

Been searching all day and still stuck on trying to access data from array object using Tempo.Tried using a variety of processes but not getting anywhere.

The array object that I'm trying to access is called options and the key is name.

`<p>{{options:name}}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of difficult to answer this without at least on instance of the array object. I would suppose you have something like this:

```
var data = {options:[
    {name:'Test Name'},
    {name:'Another Test Name'}
]}
```

Just assign the options array to the data method after prepare in Tempo:

```
Tempo.prepare('container').data(data.options);
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <p data-template>{{name}}</p>
</div>
```